# Load-balancing for real-time production environments in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say that you want to have a machine that serves up inferences to input data that and has multiple GPU cards. The inferences are made by a model with high GPU RAM requirements.  These inferences are consumed by multiple machines on the same LAN.

The input data is high volume and needs to be processed in real-time so there is a need for load-balancing among the GPU cards.  The machines that consume these inferences are load-balanced and more machines are added as the load increases.  Ideally you would add GPU cards to the single machine until it reaches its limit and then add another GPU machine.

How do you load-balance TensorFlow inferences in such a setup?